# How to show CToolTipCtrl manually in MFC

Tags: c++, mfc

I make an application that contains 2 buttons. When the mouse move into ButtonA a `CToolTipCtrl` will show. And I also want to show the tooltip when I click ButtonB but I can't make it. I read the Microsoft docs about `CToolTipCtrl` and there is no method to popup the tooltip mannually.
I tried to use `PostMessage` because `CToolTipCtrl` shows only after `PreTranslateMessage( MSG* pMsg )` was called, but also failed because I don't know how to make `MSG *pMsg`.
How to set `pMsg` in `PostMessage` or is there any way to show tooltips after I call some function?
[image]

Comment: I feel for you, the tool tip facilities in MFC are completely messed up and not well documented. It's been far too long since I had to deal with them, so I don't remember any details - only that it was a royal pain.

Comment: Why not use the CMFCButton? It has built-in tooltip support.

Comment: I feel that you are trying to use the wrong control for this. [Tooltips and Infotips](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/uxguide/ctrl-tooltips-and-infotips) offers design guidelines, and specifically a list of when to use this control. If you explain what you are ultimately trying to accomplish, you might receive better feedback.

Comment: I would follow @AndrewTruckle's advice unless I had some hard line restriction. I used it like he said some years ago and it worked perfectly fine.